# session forget in laravel 8 not working with cookie issue

Tags: laravel, session, cookies

I'm using Laravel 8.35.1 and in that I'm not able to destroy session in my Laravel project. There I also have issue with the cookie setting and removing.
There I have 3 main functions
`index() which returns the basic view which provide basic login form.`
`logincheck(Request $request) this function check the credentials provided from index() function form`
`sessionout(Request $request) it logout the current user.`
please help Thanks in advance.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Admin;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;

class CommonController extends Controller
{
  public function index()
 {
    return view('index');
 }
 public function sessionout(Request $request)
 {
  $request->session()->forget('adm');  
  Redirect::route('homepage')->send();
 }
 public function logincheck(Request $request)
 {
   $responce=array('status'=>false,'message'=>'Request not valid');
   if(!empty($request->username)&&!empty($request->password))
   {
    $admin=DB::table('admin')->where('username',$request->username)->first();
  //return response()->json($admin);
    if(empty($admin))
    {
      $responce['message']="User Not Found";
      return response()->json($responce);
    }
    if(!Hash::check($request->password, $admin->password))
    {
      $responce['message']="invalid Password";
      return response()->json($responce);
    }
    $responce['status']=true;
    $responce['message']='Login Successfull';
    $request->session()->put('adm', $admin);
    cookie('admid', $admin->id, 120); //can't set cookies
    return response($request->cookie('admid')); //checking if cookie is set and trying to get it's value if we will comment this then it will run the logincheck(Request $request) code and login will be successfull.
   }
  return response()->json($responce);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this to set cookies ...

```
    use Illuminate\Http\Response;  
    $response = new Response('Set Cookie');  
       
    $response->withCookie(cookie('admin', $admin->id, 1200));
        
    echo $response->cookie('admin');//to display cookie...
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer now i'm able to set cookie but it's not getting deleted.....and the same problem is happening with the session...it's getting set but it's not getting destroyed.

Comment: glad that i could help you...can you please accept my answer if it helped you.

Comment: I have actually used @Autista_z's 2nd answer.....and my question is still pending so i don't think i'm going to close this question.

Comment: ok fine... glad that @Autista_z's  answer helped you... ...

Answer (score 0):

First, the important thing is to understand how cookies work. Cookies cant be accessed in same request they are created. So if you make `$request->cookie('adminid')` in same method, the result will be always not set cookie or its old value.

Second `cookie('admid', $admin->id, 120);` just creates cookie, but does not save it. You have to attach cookie to response.

```
$cookie = cookie('name', 'value', $minutes);
return response('Hello World')->cookie($cookie);
```

or

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie;

Cookie::queue('name', 'value', $minutes);
```

More here: [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/responses#attaching-cookies-to-responses)

Comment: Hey your second code worked to set cookie but now i can't delete cookies and session too. Thanks for the answer and i hope you will help me destroying the cookies and the sessions too..?

Comment: For Cookie should work: `Cookie::queue(Cookie::forget('name'));` and for session `request()->session()->forget('name');`